How to upload a file to iCloud in iOS .NET MAUI?
I have a project on iOS that you can visualize, download pdf from a service and I would like them to be uploaded and saved in a folder, that can be created, but I don't have much idea how to synchronize in iCloud.
Do I need to modify something in the developer account or any specific permission?
        string fileName = nombreFile + ".pdf";

        string documentsPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);

        string path = System.IO.Path.Combine(documentsPath, fileName);

        using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
        {
            await documentStream.CopyToAsync(fileStream);
        }

I have this but I know this is saved on the device.

Does it help Saving a file to icloud drive

The first thing you will need to upload a file to ICloud is the entitlement:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/ios/entitlements?view=net-maui-8.0#icloud
This contains the following xml for the entitlement:
<key>com.apple.developer.icloud-container-identifiers</key>
<array>
  <string>iCloud.com.companyname.test</string>
</array>
<key>com.apple.developer.ubiquity-kvstore-identifier</key>
<string>$(AppIdentifierPrefix)$(CFBundleIdentifier)</string>

While the following docs are for xamarin, they may be helpful in getting the correct response, as the following Microsoft vendor states:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1665676/not-able-to-perform-read-and-write-operation-in-ic
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/xamarin/ios/data-cloud/introduction-to-icloud#finding-and-opening-icloud-documents

Thank you, I really appreciate your help
